# Issue with date formatting SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, formatting

```
SELECT LISTING_EOD.LOCATION, LISTING_EOD.APPTTIME, LISTING_EOD.PERSON_ID,
    LISTING_EOD.FORENAME, LISTING_EOD.SURNAME, LISTING_EODS.STATUS,
    LISTING_EOD.DBDATE
FROM DBNAME.LISTING_EOD LISTING_EOD;
```

This query returns a list of data processed today, I need to modify to check yesterday's data.  I have tried add the below line of code, but it doesn't return anything.  Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

```
where LISTING_EOD.DBDATE = '18-OCT-2012';
```

Comment: Its just my guess try putting 17th oct.

Comment: Do the values in `DBDATE` include a time component - since you're only looking for values that are exactly at midnight? If the query without a `where` clause only shows data from today, are you sure there is actually any data from yesterday?

Comment: @Alex Poole - There is definately data from yesterday.  the DBDATE does include a time clause.  Looks like this for example: 19-OCT-2012 09:40:31

Comment: @GrumP please post the type of dbdate column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the 'table' I was querying was a view, examined it inside sqldeveloper, and added '-1' to the sysdate. This query then returned the previous days results.

I successfully retrieved the correct data, thanks for all help received.

Answer (score 2):

If you always want yesterday's data, rather than hard-coding the date you can use:

```
WHERE LISTING_EOD.DBDATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1
AND LISTING_EOD.DBDATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

`TRUNC(SYSDATE)` gives you midnight this morning, so if run today it would give a range between `18-Oct-2010 00:00:00` and `18-Oct-2012 23:59:59`.

It's generally not a good idea to use implicit date format masks; your original code assumes your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to `DD-MON-YYYY`, but that might not be correct now (if you're seeing the time in the existing select then it probably isn't), and may well not be in the future. Always use an explicit date format mask, like `TO_DATE('18-OCT-2012', 'DD-MON-YYY')`, to avoid ambiguity and unexpected behaviour.

---

*If* the field is actually `VARCHAR2` rather than a `DATE` - which is bad - then you'll need to convert the date range to a string to get a match:

```
WHERE LISTING_EOD.DBDATE >= TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND LISTING_EOD.DBDATE <= TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

That will work for a single day, just, but you'd have problems looking for a date range. It's much better and safer to store data in a column of the appropriate type.

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't return anything though unfortunately.

Comment: @GrumP - then I'm not convinced there is matching data; can you add some output from your unrestricted query to the question. preferably showing some data form yesterday? And can you confirm the columns is of type `DATE`, and you aren't storing a date value in a `VARCHAR2` field?

Comment: I cannot show data from yesterday, at the moment the data is only showing for today's date, and it is output to an excel doc.  Here is an example of today's data: pastebin.com/qe6zGwnm

Comment: My desire is to create a query that will show yesterday's data. (18 of oct)

Comment: If it doesn't show any data for yesterday without a `where` clause at all, then adding one can't magically make that data appear. Sorry, what you're saying isn't making sense to me. Is `LISTING_EOD` actually a view that's already restricted to today?

Comment: @AlexPoole IF the column if varchar the the edit is wrong because "18 Sep 2012" is between "18 OCT" and "19 Oct" :)

Comment: @AlexPoole Hi Alex, sorry this is a view, yes.  It appears it is somehow restricted to today.  How to I get around this?  For further clarity, dbdate is a DATE.

Comment: @FlorinGhita - yes, it's worse than I suggested, you're right.

Comment: @GrumP - you cannot get around it using the view. You'd need to replicate what the view is doing but change the filters. You probably need to talk to whoever created the view, or look at the source text in `all_views`. If you need help with that you should ask a new question.

Comment: @AlexPoole I found the view in sqldeveloper and modified accordingly.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Dates in Oracle by default contain time as well. If you just specify '18-OCT-2012', it will only match 18-OCT-2012 00:00:00'. One way to get around this is to format your database date to what you are comparing it to, e.g. to_char(LISTING_EOD.DBDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') and compare this to '18-OCT-2012'. This comparison will disregard time completely.

If you had a date variable to compare with instead of a string, format this using the same date mask used for the database date. This also gets around any assumptions abut default date format on the database in question.

Comment: The `to_char()` on the table column prevents any index on that being used. I prefer converting the fixed value to match the column type, which in this case means you need to supply a range.